# What is the correct workflow for modifying child themes?

Tags: child-theme, css

I am asking the following because I am fairly new to WordPress.  I want to change the fontsize for post titles.  This is what I do:

1. I inspect a post title in Chrome using *devtools*, and find out the
   style used.
2. I edit *style.css* in the child theme and place the
   modified fontsize into the style definition used for post titles.

Is this how it's done?  If not, what is the accepted methodology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. Any changes like the ones you are doing should go into a child theme or a custom plugin. Since we are talking about CSS, which is very theme specific, changes should go into a child theme

### EDIT

From comments, and credit to @birgire,

> (*styles are*) sometimes handled by the theme itself via the theme customiser or theme options

To answer the other comment, the dev tools on browsers are excellent tools to inspect elements in order to know how that specific element is displayed. This will not only tell you the specific color/font size etc the element is using, but also the HTML tag which wraps that element and the particular class/id of that specific tag

Comment: THANK YOU so much for the confirmation.  What about the process of identifying the style?  "Inspect" is the only expeditious way, right?

Comment: Maybe we could add that it's sometimes handled by the theme itself via the theme customiser or theme options.

Comment: @birgire You are right, but I have yet to see such a theme.  Even paid themes have very little customization UI exposed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, much appreciated.